# Is there a way to delete all the rows in a table using c# and MS Access?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I want to write a simple code line that will delete all the datarows in a certain Table.
(Working with c# and MS Access 2010)
The table contains about 1000 rows, 10 columns, and it gets a bit slow.

This code does the job:

```
  connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Words\shinunonDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

  OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
  Conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
  sql = "select * from Heb";
  Conn.Open();
  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

  da.Fill(ds, "Heb");
  foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables["heb"].Rows)
  {
      dRow.Delete();
  }
  da.Update(ds, "heb");
```

But I guess there might be a shorter and more efficient way to do it.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just use a SQL command:

```
delete from Heb;
```

You can issue a SQL command on a OleDbConnection. Something like this:

```
OleDbCommand ac = new OleDbCommand("delete from Heb",Conn);
ac.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks, It's perfect!  One problem though - there is no Execute command avaliable. Should I use the ExecuteNonQuery()? What's the difference?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Bobcat100 yes, you should use ExecuteNonQuery. The difference is that this method exists, while Execute is a product of Pablo Santa Cruz's imperfect memory. More helpfully, I would add that ExecuteNonQuery is for SQL statements that do not retrieve data from the database: its integer return value indicates the number of rows affected by the command.  ExecuteScalar returns a single value from the database (e.g., calling ExecuteScalar with ”select min (Name) from USCoins” would return the string ”dime”).  Finally, of course, ExecuteQuery returns a set of rows in the form of a DbDataReader.

Comment: ExecuteQuery and DbDataReader are products of phoog's imperfect memory. They are ExecuteReader and OleDbDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works using the following lines:

```
OleDbCommand ac = new OleDbCommand("delete from Heb",Conn);
ac.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But it deletes all my data from the table, not just a row.

and when I do this

```
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from Kunden where id=" + txtKdnID.Text + " ", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Eintrag erfolgreich gelöscht");
```

I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOciB.jpg).